# Free Linux like "tail -f" for Windows

Tags: windows, monitoring, utilities

Is there alternative to [hoo-wintail](http://www.hootech.com/WinTail/) (costs $49.95) for Windows, which can color specific lines according to pattern in monitored file.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found two options:

**[BareTail](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/)**

[image]

**[Tail for Win32](http://tailforwin32.sourceforge.net/)**

[image]

Neither of them uses Cygwin. BareTail apparently has an annoying startup screen. Tail for Win32 is completely free, and open source.

Answer (score 3):

multitail acts like tail -f on multiple files at a time, and it will color lines according to the file type.  It's available in Windows as part of [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com), which will cost you $0.

Comment: Installing Cygwin seems like overkill just to get a version of tail, no matter how spiffy it is.

Comment: Matter of taste, but I'll take that over paying $50 for a single-use utility any day.  And that after all is what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 3):

Text utilities from gnuwin32 contains tail.
This distribution is a zip file, you can only use tail.exe from this zip.
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm

It has a dependency. (dep is dependency,bin is actual distribution) Download both of them,extract. Copy

1. libiconv2.dll
2. libintl3.dll

from dep to same directory as tail.exe

http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/coreutils/5.3.0/coreutils-5.3.0-dep.zip/download
http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/coreutils/5.3.0/coreutils-5.3.0-bin.zip/download
Then tail.exe works normally. But as you say in comments it gives error for "tail -f filename"

Interesting thing is: If you install using their setup package
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/downlinks/coreutils.php. 
This error does not exist. But I saw same error when I was trying to use from zip distribution only.

Comment: Nice, hovewer "tail -f <file>" prints the fail and immediately closes upon error "Bad file descriptor" + "tail: no file remaining"

Comment: Sorry I added dependency for more information but this is not same error you mentioned. I will look at it.

Comment: Not sure if this helps you, but I ran into the same "Bad file descriptor" error with tail.exe v5.3.0 - and I worked around it by using "tail -F" (big F) instead of "tail -f".

Comment: @BillAgee, thanks so much for that!  I had the same problem, but -F fixes the problem w/ -f on windows.

Comment: Thanks @BillAgee, this has been bugging me for ages!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

"A Windows version of the UNIX 'tail' command. Includes features such as pager or SMTP notification of specific items found within the files being monitored"

http://sourceforge.net/projects/tailforwin32/

HTH

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend [LogExpert](http://www.log-expert.de/) an other [alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/software/logexpert/)

Answer (score 0):

[Free version of Kiwi Syslog Viewer will do the job.](http://www.kiwisyslog.com/kiwi-log-viewer-overview/)

It has a tail function, and will open very large files quickly and easily.